# EventHandler null due to multiple instanciation

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

My project follows the MVVM pattern. What I need to do is to change the view when an ObservableCollection is changed in the model. To do so I wanted to use an eventHandler in the model and set a listener in the ViewModel.

My problem is that my viewModel class is instantiated only once (when we first access to the matching view). But my model class can be re-instantiated depending on the user needs. So everything works well as long as the user doesn't trigger the creation of a new model class. But after that my eventhandler is re-set to null and as my ViewModel is not re-instantiate I don't re-subscribe to it. So it stays null and my viewModel stops being aware of the model state.

What I currently do is to force the view to update itself, by sending a message to the viewModel, every times the user access it. (Via the codebehind, onNavigatedTo()) But it's not optimal as the model may not have changed and I recompute everything nevertheless.

I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it? Like having a static eventHandler (tried but wasn't able to make it work) or being able to set the listener in the ViewModel class from de configprojet constructor.

My class in my model which use an eventHandler. The eventHandler ListeValidationCollectionChanged is triggered by a change in one of my two ObservableCollection.

```cs
public class ConfigProjet : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler ListeRapportschanged;
    public event EventHandler ListeFicheschanged;

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler ListeValidationCollectionChanged;

    public ConfigProjet()
    { }

    private void Validation_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseValidationCollectionChanged(e);
    }


    private void RaiseValidationCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListeValidationCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            ListeValidationCollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void RaiseValidationChanged()
    {
        if (ListeRapportschanged != null)
        {
            ListeRapportschanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (ListeFicheschanged != null)
        {
            ListeFicheschanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> listeFichesAValider;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListeFichesAValider
    {
        get { return this.listeFichesAValider; }
        set
        {
            if (this.listeFichesAValider != value)
            {
                if (listeFichesAValider != null)
                {
                    //Desabonneemnt
                    listeFichesAValider.CollectionChanged -= Validation_CollectionChanged;
                }

                this.listeFichesAValider = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListeFichesAValider");

                if (listeFichesAValider != null)
                {
                    //abonnement
                    listeFichesAValider.CollectionChanged += Validation_CollectionChanged;
                }

                RaiseValidationChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> listeRapportsAValider;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListeRapportsAValider
    {
        get { return this.listeRapportsAValider; }
        set
        {
            if (this.listeRapportsAValider != value)
            {
                if (listeRapportsAValider != null)
                {
                    //Desabonneemnt
                    listeRapportsAValider.CollectionChanged -= Validation_CollectionChanged;
                }

                this.listeRapportsAValider = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListeRapportsAValider");

                if (listeRapportsAValider != null)
                {
                    //abonnement
                    listeRapportsAValider.CollectionChanged += Validation_CollectionChanged;
                }

                RaiseValidationChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my viewModel class :

```cs
public class ProjetsWorkFlowVueModele : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProjetsWorkFlowVueModele()
    {            
        //used to by-pass my problem, message send by the code-behind on navigationTo event :
        Messenger.Default.Register<ListeFichiersAValiderChangedMessage>(this, OnListeFichiersAValiderChanged);

        Donnees.Instance.ConfigP.ListeFicheschanged += ConfigP_ListeFicheChanged;
        Donnees.Instance.ConfigP.ListeRapportschanged += ConfigP_ListeRapportChanged;
        Donnees.Instance.ConfigP.ListeValidationCollectionChanged += ConfigP_ListeValidationCollectionChanged;

        CreerListeFiche();
        CreerListeRapport();
    }

    private void OnListeFichiersAValiderChanged(ListeFichiersAValiderChangedMessage obj)
    {
        //on rafraichit les listes
        CreerListeFiche();
        CreerListeRapport();
    }

    private void ConfigP_ListeRapportChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreerListeRapport();
    }

    private void ConfigP_ListeFicheChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreerListeFiche();
    }

    private void ConfigP_ListeValidationCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreerListeFiche();
        CreerListeRapport();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1 :**

The terms I use, Model, view and viewModel refer to the MVVM implementation pattern. The idea is to separate the view (Ui + Ui logic) from the model (data + business logic) by using a view model between them. So all the presentation logic, data for the view and state are computed in the viewModel. That means that there must be as less as possible logic in the code-behind of the view. In MVVM the dataContext of the view is set to the viewModel. Then you bind elements of the view to the elements of the viewModel. The viewModel may choose to use its own data to bind or can expose data from the model (in this case the class must support databinding) to the view. The model can communicate through INotifyProperty/CollectionChanged (so the view or the viewModel is aware of any change).

I have two project one for the model and another for the viewModel + view. The first project (model) have no reference whatsoever to the second. However, the second can access fields of the model.

I was not very clear when I spoke about my model, view, etc. as there are multiple model class doing different things and so on.
In my case, I have a class in my model, which represent the data of a project. Therefore, it is re-created when the user change from one project to another (the command is fired from the UI and process by the matching viewModel (raise a OnpropertyChanged) and then in one class of my model (react to the OnPropertyChanged) I create a new Instance of another model class: configProjet). Therefore, the problem is I create multiple instance of the configProjet model class, but only one of my viewmodel class. My eventHandler (in my model class) is re-instanciate but not the listener (in the viewModel classe). So the eventHandler stay null because no listener subscribes to it.

I hope I was clear :x

I apologies for my English as I'm not a native speaker.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most of this question is precise detail about stuff that doesn't matter (e.g. CollectionChanged handlers have nothing to do with your question), but the critical information is hopelessly vague: It sounds like your views create their own viewmodels. Is that correct? If so, that's a major design flaw that's creating a lot of problems for you. Can you explain, in detail, what the viewmodel and the "model" are, and how they interact? What part of your code recreates the model? How, and when does that happen? How is it hidden from the viewmodel? What IS the model? Another viewmodel?

Comment: When you ask a question with big blocks of code, please take the time to format the code properly.